# wildfly 8.2 start fails on javaagent in vm argument

Tags: java, aspectj, wildfly, wildfly-8, load-time-weaving

I am new to wildfly8 and also new for aspectJ.
Wildfly 8.2 startup is getting failled if i add javaagent argument in VM argument for aspectjWeaver.jar for LTW(load time weaving) purpose.

```
 -javaagent:"D:\Installables\JBOSS-8-Tools\aop\sample aspectJ  project\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar"
```

Than i am getting below log manager error:

```
WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
Feb 11, 2015 4:55:43 PM org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
Feb 11, 2015 4:55:43 PM org.jboss.as.server.ApplicationServerService start
INFO: JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" starting
Feb 11, 2015 4:55:50 PM org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext executeStep
ERROR: JBAS014612: Operation ("parallel-extension-add") failed - address: ([])
java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS014670: Failed initializing module org.jboss.as.logging
at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$1.execute(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:111)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:660)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:501)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:298)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:293)
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:324)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:297)
at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:356)
at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:331)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:259)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011592: The logging subsystem requires the log manager to be org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager. The subsystem has not be initialized and cannot be used. To use JBoss Log Manager you must add the system property "java.util.logging.manager" and set it to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$1.execute(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:103)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011592: The logging subsystem requires the log manager to be org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager. The subsystem has not be initialized and cannot be used. To use JBoss Log Manager you must add the system property "java.util.logging.manager" and set it to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingExtension.initialize(LoggingExtension.java:122)
at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionAddHandler.initializeExtension(ExtensionAddHandler.java:98)
at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:139)
at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

Feb 11, 2015 4:55:50 PM org.jboss.as.server.ServerService boot
FATAL: JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner;  exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

Now if i add below two vm arguments along with if i add jboss-logmanager-1.3.1.Final.jar in bootstarp path than above stated exception will not appear but the below exception for log formatter will be appeared and again wildfly will not be started.
two VM arguments:

```
-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager 
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
```

Error Stack trace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$1.applyPostCreate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:175)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$1.applyPostCreate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:156)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.doApplyPostCreate(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:276)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.commit(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:261)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:393)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:92)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:300)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:262)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:320)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:318)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:318)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:300)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:265)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1468)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1466)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:204)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:339)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:393)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.Jdk14Trace.<init>(Jdk14Trace.java:26)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.Jdk14TraceFactory.getTrace(Jdk14TraceFactory.java:17)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.<clinit>(Aj.java:52)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.<clinit>(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:32)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Agent.<clinit>(Agent.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:382)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:397)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered an unknown format character
    at org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.FormatStringParser.getSteps(FormatStringParser.java:172)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter.setPattern(PatternFormatter.java:63)
    ... 36 more
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Operation failed
    at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.operationFailed(AsyncFutureTask.java:74)
    at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.get(AsyncFutureTask.java:268)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:312)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:460)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.as.server-controller: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logmanager/handlers/SyslogHandler$SyslogType
    at org.jboss.as.domain.management.audit.SyslogAuditLogHandlerResourceDefinition.<clinit>(SyslogAuditLogHandlerResourceDefinition.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.management.audit.AccessAuditResourceDefinition.registerChildren(AccessAuditResourceDefinition.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.ConcreteResourceRegistration.registerSubModel(ConcreteResourceRegistration.java:160)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.management.CoreManagementResourceDefinition.registerChildren(CoreManagementResourceDefinition.java:115)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.ConcreteResourceRegistration.registerSubModel(ConcreteResourceRegistration.java:160)
    at org.jboss.as.server.controller.resources.ServerRootResourceDefinition.registerChildren(ServerRootResourceDefinition.java:394)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService$DelegatingResourceDefinition.registerChildren(ServerService.java:448)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.ManagementResourceRegistration$Factory.create(ManagementResourceRegistration.java:594)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.start(AbstractControllerService.java:241)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.start(ServerService.java:247)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.SyslogHandler$SyslogType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:386)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
    ... 15 more
```

Can anybody suggest whats more is required to run wildfly8.2 with aspectjWeaver.jar in javaagent VM for load time weaving.

Answer (score 1):

Use jboss-logmanager-2.0.0.Beta1.jar in bootstrap. It worked for me. As classes which throw exception are not available in jboss-logmanager-1.3.1.Final.jar.